# Register my App with <intent-filter> not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having trouble opening an XML from the "Google Files App" file to do internal processing in my app, despite using an intent filter in the manifest file.

Here's what I've done:

- I use an XML file named data.xml in the Download directory of my app.
- I added the following intent filter to the  from my MainActivity element in my app's manifest file:

```xml
<activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:exported="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <!-- Main -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Register XML -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/xml" />
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
```

Here are some things I've tried:

- I made sure that the XML file is well-formed.
- I made sure that the intent filter is correct.
- I tried using different MIME types.

Nothing has worked so far. I'm working on an app with SDK 33.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT` with `android.intent.action.VIEW`.

Comment: Same result, with VIEW, my IDE give a highlighting Error "AppLinkUriError"

Comment: @lupaulus: I am uncertain how you are using the Google Files app, then. You could try `SEND` instead of `VIEW`, I suppose. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters?hl=en#AddIntentFilter) for more on advertising your app via an `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: I click on my xml file in the `Downloads`folder and try to `Open With`, I receive `There is no app for opening this type of file`

Comment: @lupaulus: Personally, I never bother with this approach, preferring to use the Storage Access Framework and triggering the file-open option from within my app. It is possible that Google Files is using a different MIME type. You could try `*/*` instead of `application/xml` as an experiment. If that works, Logcat show show your activity being launched and you can see what MIME type Google Files is using.

Comment: Yeah, seems not be working either. Yes, I tried this workaround, because I didn't like SAF and would not rely on it.

Comment: And from the SDK 30, the SAF can't access the `Download` directory

Comment: @lupaulus: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` works with `Downloads/`.

Comment: Yes `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, but I have no idea what is the document name because the XML come from outside, that's why I need to open the folder tree with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` with SAF

Comment: @lupaulus: "I have no idea what is the document name" -- wrap the `Uri` for the document in `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`, then call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` to get a display name for the document.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the `AndroidManifest.xml` did not be updated or notify the system about the `<intent-filter>`, if the app is reinstalled from Android Studio.

To make it work, **I remove my App completely from my device and reinstall it.**